# Python OpenPyxl: How to iterate through 1 Row's columns to find a value

Tags: python, openpyxl

When using Python OpenPyxl, how would I iterate through 1 Row's columns to find a value?

Here's my current (failing) attempt -- (There appears to be an error in (at least) my 2nd for loop.)

> ```
> book = openpyxl.load_workbook(excelFile)
> for sheet in book.worksheets: #For each worksheet
>     for colidx in sheet.iter_cols(sheet.min_col,sheet.max_col): #For each column in a worksheet
>         if sheet.cell(1,colidx).value == "ValueImLookingFor": #Check each column in Row #1 for value
>             print ("ValueImLookingFor is in cell A" + colidx)
> ```

Thanks so much for your help,

CG

Comment: `iter_cols()` returns columns, not indices. If you're using `ws.iter_cols()` there is no need to use `ws.cell()` in the same loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('C:/Users/viupadhy/Desktop/Results.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
count=0
while count < (ws.max_column):
    for row in ws.rows:
        if row[count].value == "CCL":
            print(row)
    count+=1
```

The output will be the tulpe of indexes.

```
(<Cell 'Results'.A10>, <Cell 'Results'.B10>, <Cell 'Results'.C10>, <Cell 'Results'.D10>)
```

You can parse the exact indexes from tuple if you want!!!

Comment: Hi Vishal, thanks much, but please pardon my newbie-like question:
The above results in:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'row' referenced before assignment
...Unfortunately I've been trying to figure out how to do an initial assignment of "row" with the above Python snippet for a longgg time with no luck.  Would you know how to do that, please?  Thanks, CG

Comment: @user25127 no problem, You're using `row` variable when its value is *none* in your script, just write `global row` at top or change `row` variable name to `row1` in for loop. Let me know if error still exists.

Comment: TY though unfortunately no luck with those two ideas.
  Same error when adding "global row" at the top.  I then tried changing row to row1 in the for loop, which resulted in a similar error. (NameError: name 'row1' is not defined).  I then also tried changing the global statement to "global row1", but also failed with the same error.  If it helps any, I'm using Python 3.6.8.

Comment: @user25127 If your code is not confidential then can you send me the link of your code by uploading it on gdrive or somewhere?